# Differentiation with respect to vector

Tags: vector-analysis, calculus

I have a function,
$$ K\left(\nabla u \right) = \left(K_0 + K_1 \textrm{norm} \left(\nabla u \right)^2 \right) \nabla u $$
and I want to differentiate $K$ with respect to $ \nabla u $.

I will try to rephrase this question,
let$$\nabla u = e$$

$$e = e\left(e_1, e_1 \right)$$
This is more like $$ K\left(\nabla u \right) = K\left(e \right) $$
If I have $$ K\left(e_1, e_1 \right) $$
e is a vector $$e \in R^2$$ and k is a function that takes a vector as an input and gives a vector as an output. $$K \in R^2$$

I want derivative/gradient of $$K$$.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is more a math question. I've voted to migrate this to the math exchange.

Comment: You differentiate with regards to a variable, which is not the case for $\nabla u$. Can you clarify your question ? Or does it mean that $\nabla u$ is the name of a variable like $v$ or whatever else ? Also, you need to tell us what your norm is.

Comment: So do you have a function of two variables and you want the total derivative? Is this your function: $K(x,y)=(K_0+K_1(x^2+y^2))\cdot (x,y)$, with $K_0,K_1$ being constants? But then it takes value in $\mathbb R^2$ and not $\mathbb R$, right? In general, it is not at all clear (at least to me) what any of your symbols mean.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the vector
$$
\mathbf{k}
= (k_0+k_1 \| \mathbf{x} \|^2) \mathbf{x}
$$
with $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

From what I understand, you are asking for the Jacobian.
Using differentials (and product rule), we have
$$
\mathrm{d}\mathbf{k}
=
(k_0+k_1 \| \mathbf{x} \|^2) \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}
+
k_1 \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}
$$
from which you deduce that
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{k}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
=
(k_0+k_1 \| \mathbf{x} \|^2) \mathbf{I}_N
+
k_1 \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T
$$
where $\mathbf{I}_N$ is the identity matrix.